# DM script to calculate area under a curve with given ROI

Tags: dm-script

I want to calculate the area under a curve with giving ROI, like the attached picture, I want to get the area under the green curve from 13 to 30, could we reach this function by DM scripting?

Never done similar things before, any suggestions thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the image is of label "A" then, you can simply do:
`sum( A[] )`

or, a bit more elaborated:

```c
image img := GetFrontImage()
number integral = sum( img[] )
result("\n The intensity of the selected region in image [")
result( img.imageGetLabel() + "]:" + img.ImageGetName() + " is: ")
result( integral)
```

Note that this will give you the integral (or just the sum of channel-values) in *raw numbers*. If you have calibrated the intensity, you will have to take the calibration into account.
If - as in most cases - you just have an intensity scale but no offset, it is straight forward:

```c
image img := GetFrontImage()
number integral = sum( img[] )
number scale = img.ImageGetIntensityScale()
number integral_cal = integral * scale
result("\n The intensity of the selected region in image [")
result( img.imageGetLabel() + "]:" + img.ImageGetName() + " is: ")
result( integral_cal )
```

If you also have an origin, it becomes:

```c
image img := GetFrontImage()
number integral = sum( img[] )
number scale = img.ImageGetIntensityScale()
number origin = img.ImageGetIntensityOrigin()

number t,l,b,r
img.GetSelection(t,l,b,r)
number nChannels = r - l
number integral_cal = (integral - origin * nChannels) * scale

result("\n The intensity of the selected region in image [")
result( img.imageGetLabel() + "]:" + img.ImageGetName() + " is: ")
result( integral_cal )
```